# Azure Function (Python) - Set Timezone For Timer Trigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

**ISSUE**

I am trying to setup my UTC CRON job in my Azure Function App to run based on EST/EDT timezone.

My thought is that you enter in your CRON time for your desired timezone, and then via the Azure portal set the configuration option `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` to `America/New_York` (see image that shows Azure Function is running Linux and not Windows).

[image]
[image]

**MORE INFO**

According to the below, 08:30 UTC should be 04:30 EDT currently. So that is when I am expecting the monitor to run. It is still running via the CRON job at 08:30 UTC instead of 08:30 Eastern time (04:30 EDT).

https://www.freeconvert.com/time/utc-to-est

[image]

*Using Python*
[image]

Comment: Are you running it on a consumption plan ? According to the documentation, it is not supported for consumption plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-time-zones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per July 2022, this is not supported for Linux Function App running on a consumption plan (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-time-zones)):

> `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan.

Answer (score 1):

***According to [Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-time-zones) it says,***

> In configuration add app settings WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set value to America/New_York

> `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan.

[image]

Then save it

[image]

***Output:***

***You get the desired output in Desired Time Zone***

[image]

***Taken References from:***

- [Timer trigger for Azure Functions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-time-zones)

***Update: Done in Linux plan only***

[image]

Comment: I am using the Linux plan. So this answer is not a answer.

Comment: I have reproduced in linux plan only, you can check the operating system and i have updated my answer to show that

Comment: @RithwikBojja - You are using the `P1v2` dedicated app service plan & not the serverless/consumption tier and hence it is working for you. As per the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python#ncrontab-time-zones , it is not supported.