# Azure Functions Timer Trigger - Day Light Saving

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am using an Python Function in Azure Functions with a timer trigger.  The timer is set for 3am, but its firing at 4am. I live in UK so the time zone changes from UTC to UTC+1 and back through out the year.  In the Azure Portal, in the configuration tab, I have added an application setting for 'WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE' with parameters:

1. 'Europe/London'
2. 'GB'

Both of these stay at UTC, does anyone know if there is a way to automatically account for day light saving and not just manually change this when the clocks change?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 articles I referred to.  First is [this](https://dev.to/azure/getting-rid-of-time-zone-issues-within-azure-functions-4066), where it says that the instances are created with a default time zone of UTC.

Within the link, it gives another [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)?WT.mc_id=devto-blog-marouill#time-zones). This link mentions that the time zone for London should be set to "GMT Standard Time". Can you give this a shot and see how you go?

Comment: Hello, that doest work.  But I have tried to change it to another time zone and it wont change to that either.  Im reading online that its set by the location you select when creating the app?

Comment: What is the location of your app? If isn't in the London region can you try creating it there ?

Comment: So there is another post on here which says it not support on a Linux Function App.

As per July 2022, this is not supported for Linux Function App running on a consumption plan (see documentation):

WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan.

Comment: @Dave_The_Noob Yes, this is documented in the official documentation as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_time_zone

Answer (score 0):

So there is another post on here which says it not support on a Linux Function App. 'As per July 2022, this is not supported for Linux Function App running on a consumption plan (see documentation): WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan.'

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73042840/15565242